# How do I create a custom field which contains multiple data type?

Tags: custom-field, data-types

I want to create a field with a question (e.g. How was the service of employee x) and allow the employer to pick a result (e.g. good, average, bad) as well as to add comments. However, while i believe the question can be part of the description of the field and the data type for the result a picklist, I also want to associate a textbox data type for additional comments. How might I do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can create a Picklist to capture result as Good, Avg or Bad and a Text field (text area as per your req) and have validation rule in place to make sure some value is entered if a result is chosen. Or if these fields are in a Custom built page/component you can handle the situation via code.

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar yes but how might I link both the result and the comment to the question if there are multiple questions on a page.

Comment: You just need to create two fields, One as a question with picklist values and a description field(text area) which you can mandate on filling the above picklist field.

Comment: Sorry if am missing something here, I couldn't understand by linking them.

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar No worries, I am just a little new with Salesforce and am still trying to figure things out. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot create a field with multiple datatype, instead you can create two fields(or multiple as required) and have a validation rule setup to make sure all the field values are captured.

For example:
In the below screenshot, **Main Competitor(s)**(text field) is mandatory as **Stage**(picklist) field is populated.
[image]
**Once the record is saved, it would look something like this**
[image]

**If there are multiple fields, you can align them in one section,**
[image]

Or, via code you can create a component that can show two input fields(a picklist and a text) with the same Name and on save one can concatenate those two values into one field.

This way you can achieve the requirement.